# Firebase query inside onMarkerClick is not working properly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity in which I'm getting the data from Firebase database and showing multiple markers on the map. In onMarkerClick, I want the user to go to another activity that have details about the marker that was tapped. On first tap on the marker, it shows the title only and on second tap it goes to the other activity after doing Firebase database query to get the id for that marker so that the correct details will be provided about the tapped marker.

The problem is when I tap on any marker the first time, and then If I click on any other marker, the opened activity opens up the details of the marker that was tapped first.

If I tap on the same marker twice, it works fine. But when I come back to the map activity, tapping on any marker first time, will open up the details for the marker that was previously tapped.

What can be done to do the correct query inside onMarkerClick.

Here's the code.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        eventTitle = marker.getTitle();

        q = database.getReference("events")
                .orderByChild("event_title")
                .equalTo(marker.getTitle());

        q.addValueEventListener(vel);

        Intent intent = new Intent(NearbyEventsActivity.this, EventDetailActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("eventid", eventid);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        if (eventid != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return false;
    }

    ValueEventListener vel = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Event e = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                eventid = e.getEvent_id();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: Are you using a double click listener to listen to second tap?

Comment: No, I'm not. The code I posted is the only code for the click listener. On first tap it only shows marker and does query, but If I tap any other marker, It opens up the details of the marker that was tapped first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is when I tap on any marker the first time, and then If I click on any other marker, the opened activity opens up the details of the marker that was tapped first.

Firebase query executes asyncronously. Your `ValueEventListener` will not be called immediately.

Use your secound Activity start code inside `onDataChange` method.

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Event e = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
            eventid = e.getEvent_id();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(NearbyEventsActivity.this, EventDetailActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("eventid", eventid);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        if (eventid != null) {
         startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```